# Providing input to arduino form ROS

Tags: arduino, ros

Let us assume I have a random 4 character string generated every 1 second in ROS and that same string need to be given to Arduino as input from ROS so further it can transmit it using the RF module. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: What is your physical setup? Do you have a Linux / Ubuntu system connected via USB-Serial to the arduino?

Comment: Show your attempt. Define ROS.  And this is not a volunteer system-design workshop.  "How can I achieve that" is a system-level question.  You don't specify what parts you'll use, what interfaces they employ, etc.  Learn how to use the site and ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give specifics without knowing more about your setup, but here is a suggestion.

Assuming that you can connect the Arduino by some cable to the computer running your ROS node, you could transfer the 4 characters via serial. You would need to open the serial port corresponding to the Arduino in your ROS node, send the characters and parse the data on your Arduino using the Serial class. Once parsed, you can pass it along to your RF module on the Arduino.